# Unable to view GUI in ubuntu 14.04do

Tags: 12.04

I am unable to view the GUI in ubuntu 14.04. I followed the previous answers but, I am not able to run the given command too.
The sudo command is not found.
I am not able to install the sudo too.
I am in

**(initramfs)**

Please do help me here. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are stuck in initramfs it means you have a corrupt installation. Did you have it functioning beforehand? If it loaded what it did it means it could not load the rest of the modules because a critical one is either deleted, misplaced, or corrupted.